# Не загружается класс драйвера sqlite в методе сериализуемого класса

Tags: gwt, rpc, java, sqlite

Имеется сериализуемый класс для обмена по gwt-rpc. Один из методов класса работает с БД sqlite.
Приложение не загружается, первая ошибка указывает на строку

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

метода сериализуемого класса и пишет:
"The method forName(String) is undefined for the type Class".

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в загрузке класса "org.sqlite.JDBC". Попробовал разные варианты, в том числе эти

```
MyClass.getClassLoader().loadClass("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
Class.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

результат тот же: "The method getClassLoader() is undefined for the type Class<class>"
Можно ли решить проблему?

Comment: GWT форма тоже не может загрузить этот класс. Может это связано с ограничениями gwt вытекающих из компиляции в JavaScript'ы?

Comment: А просто на сервере он грузится ? Я не совсем понял, какая часть приложения ругается (постепенно доходит, что браузерная - очевидно там класса нет).

Зачем Вам драйвер базы в shared ?

Comment: На сервере грузится, не грузится на клиенте. Нужно было, что бы класс, которым взаимодействует rpc, мог работать с sqlite. Хотя и метод этот предполагался вызываться только на стороне сервера, он же попадает в gwt модуль, где свой класс лоадер, который похоже не умеет с sqlite работать, ему это и не надо наверное. У gwt свой компилятор, он то и выдает ошибки.

Comment: Переделайте класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На клиеннте это и не должно работать. GWT не реализует метод Class.forName. И тем более нельзя подгружать такие классы. Как вы себе представляете это будет работать?

Решение простое: сделайте нормально и не мешайте всё в кучу. В shared на 90% - это всякие сериализуемые бины, а остальные 10% - это универсальные utils. Если ваш класс подразумевает сериализацию, то вероятно это бин с данными. Ясно что надо выделить логику по работе с базой подальше от него, так как вы нарушили одно из важнейших правил при разработке: разделение ответственностей. Как бонус вы получите отсутствие подобных проблем с GWT.

Comment: Понимаю, все мои проблемы, наверное, являются следствием отсутствия опыта web-программирования и вообще клиент-серверного ПО. Мы переписывает старое ПО для веб. Классы переписал, вроде все аккуратно получилось.